# How can I share text on a Windows 10 App?

Tags: windows-phone, winjs, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am building a Windows 10 Web App by Project Westminster. I want to create a button to invoke the native share capability, sharing some text I have. I have the below codes. Clicking on my button would call the share() function.

```
function share() {
    Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.showShareUI();
}

function shareTextHandler(e) {
        var request = e.request;
        request.data.properties.title = "Share Text Example";
        request.data.properties.description = "Demonstrates how to share.";
        request.data.setText("Hello World!");
 }

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // This app is newly launched. Register the app as share source.
        var dataTransferManager = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.getForCurrentView();
            dataTransferManager.addEventListener("datarequested", shareTextHandler);
        } else {
                // TODO: This app was reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore the app state here.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
 };
```

But now when I click on the button, it will share the screen captured on my app,  not the text I intended to share. How can I correct the behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: I think this is because .showShareUI simply shows the share UI in its default form, it will not use the shareTextHandler code you have written where the content being shared is set. What happens if you invoke the share screen using the native controls rather than your own button?